# Getting API latency inside of a commandhandler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Making a ping command for my bot,
want to show the api latency with `Math.round(client.ws.ping)`, when I use it inside of my index.js, it works fine. When I use it inside of my ping command in my command handler, it won't work and returns to `NaN`.

Do I need to require something to use it?

Here is my code inside of ping.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'measures ping',
    execute(message, args){
            async function pingFunction(){
                const embedPingtest = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Pinging...')
                .setColor(0xC1CCDE)
                const msg = await message.channel.send(embedPingtest);

                const embedPing = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Pong!')
                .setDescription("Bot Latency: ``" + Math.floor(msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp) + " ms``\nAPI Latency: ``" + Math.round(client.ws.ping) + " ms``")
                .setColor(0xC1CCDE)
                console.log(apiLatency)
                msg.edit(embedPing)
            
            }
            pingFunction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you create a new client instance. This one doesn't has a ping as it is not logged in so not online. I suggest you pass your old instance as function parameter, to make your code look something like:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'measures ping',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        (async () => {
           const embedPingtest = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Pinging...')
                .setColor(0xC1CCDE)
            const msg = await message.channel.send(embedPingtest);

            const embedPing = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Pong!')
                .setDescription("Bot Latency: ``" + Math.floor(msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp) + " ms``\nAPI Latency: ``" + Math.round(client.ws.ping) + " ms``")
                .setColor(0xC1CCDE)
            console.log(apiLatency)
            msg.edit(embedPing)
        })();
    }
}
```

I know most guides only make you using the structure of `run(message, args)` but in my bot I usually use `message, args, client?` (mine works different tho as I modified my module structure). This also won't throw an error in your code, as JS doesn't care how many arguments you pass or don't pass.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `Discord.Client()`, you could refer to Zer0's answer, or an even easier way would to just use the `message` object.

`message` has a `client` property, which will return the client that instantiated the message.

Instead of:

```js
Math.round(client.ws.ping)
```

Use:

```js
Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)
```